# Same Domain cookie set inside iframe is not accessible outside

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, cookies

I have a page from domain1.com which includes another page in domain2.com. The domain2.com page sets some cookies. The cookies are accessible inside the iframe but when I try to open another page from domain2.com the cookies are not available. 
   This is working fine in other browsers, I tried setting p3p policy and all but still not effect.

Regards,
Jishnu

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the domain of the [cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) to your whole website domain? I ran into a problem like this but if you change up the domain, it lets you access them

Example:

`setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/", "example.com", 1);`

will be available in every page under `www.example.com`

**EDIT**

I believe the answer you are looking for is here: [Cookies in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012633/facebook-php-page-tab-app-session-does-not-sustain-when-a-user-closes-their/19012868#19012868)