# Facebook PHP page tab app - $_SESSION does not sustain when a user closes their browser window

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-php-sdk

I have a page tab app that is a contest with a like gate.

A user likes a page, provides their email address and hits submit to enter the contest.

After they enter, I set a session variable $_SESSION['entered'] = '1'; or something similar

Once they enter, I show more information on the page(html) and remove the email form.

**PROBLEM: If the users stays on the page, refreshes it a million times (in the same browser window), the session variable stays and I'm able to tell that the user has entered and display the correct info.**

**If the user closes the window, comes back later in a new window, etc. I lose the session information and the user is presented with the enter form again (although they've already entered the contest)**

How do I sustain the session for the user in the page app if they leave and come back?

Comment: I feel like I just need a piece of data to hold on to for the user, but I'm not getting anything in the signed request for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) instead. Sessions will close out on exiting the browser, but cookies will last until the expiration date is reached on them.

You could also set it up that they have to log in, and in their user, you set whether they have entered the contest or not and adjust the page accordingly. (just an idea...)

Comment: Unfortunately, the cookie is not sticking also. I believe this is due to the iframe.

Comment: Have you tried setting the domain of the cookie to your whole website domain. I ran into a problem like this but if you change up the domain, it lets you access them. The example is in the php link I put in my answer. **EX:** `setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/", "example.com", 1);` will be available in every page under www.example.com

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks for your help, I had the setcookie in the wrong place (before output) and it caused the cookie not to be set. You walk continuing to write answers helped me jog my silliness.  Using a cookie should work - never know what facebook is doing in that iframe proxy, I assumed they were clearing cookies when mine didn't work. Thank you again for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are destroyed by the browser when closed - nothing code wise will change how browsers handle that. You can try a cookie instead, or try to save the session to their IP/useragent (wouldn't recommend for security though) and reestablish it when they come back.

Comment: Is this a facebook thing? Sessions are not destroyed in PHP by closing the browser window.

Comment: The cookie is also not sticking, I believe this is due to the iframe. Anyone else solved this riddle before?

Comment: the session is not destroyed by php it's destroyed by the browser in this instance. facebook sets a cookie that ties to a session, so although user data isn't stored on the client a token that allows that user to pull back his session is stored in a cookie on the client side. without this cookie, facebook sessions would be lost as well. this is the type of functionality you need to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As written by others Sessions are destroyed if a user closes the browser. i won`t use cookies on your side either. I suggest you to get the users uid and check your database if the user has already entered the form and display the correct page after you have this info.

This might be a more secure and consistent way than sessions or cookies.

Greets